# Android Support PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use Support Library's PreferenceFragment, but for some reason it looks really ugly on Pre-Lollipop

this is my preferences

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="pref_dark"
            android:summary="@string/pref_dark"
            android:title="@string/dark" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/others">
        <Preference
            android:key="pref_about"
            android:summary="@string/pref_about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and this is my theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="numPanel">@color/numPanel</item>
    <item name="funcPanel">@color/funcPanel</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cairo_semibold</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

[image: Preferences on API 17]

What am I doing wrong? I tried using support preferences in XML but didn't make any changes.

Comment: which android version you got the screenshot from?

Comment: and please include your activity declaration